# Next js getting double result

Tags: reactjs, next.js, router

I am trying to build a web application using next js. Router Push is working fine, it's redirect to login page, but after redirect in login page i am getting double notification. where the problem? i want to show only one notification. please help me.

(1) dashboard Page

```
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import { useContext } from "react";
import { toast } from "react-toastify";
import AppContext from "../../components/AppContext";
import DashLayout from "../../layouts/DashLayout";

function DashMain() {
    const router = useRouter();
    const server = useContext(AppContext);

    if (!server.auth) {
        router.push("/auth/login");
        toast.success("Please login to access dashboard");
    }

    return (
        <>
            {server.auth ?
                <h2>Welcome to Dashboard</h2>
                :
                <h1>Please login to access dashboard</h1>
            }
        </>
    );

}

export default DashMain;
```

(2) Login Page

```
import { useContext, useState } from "react";
import Head from "next/head";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import Link from "next/link";
import Image from "next/image";
import AppContext from "../../components/AppContext";
import { toast } from "react-toastify";
import MainLayout from "../../layouts/MainLayout";

function Login() {

    const server = useContext(AppContext);
    const router = useRouter();

    if (server.auth) {
        router.push("/");
        toast.success("You are already logged In");
    }

    //states
    const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
    const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
    const [errors, setErrors] = useState("");

    //Login Submit
    const submitForm = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        server.login({ email, password, setErrors });
    }

    if (server.userLoding) {
        return (
            <div id="mainmodal">
                <div className="modalconent">
                    <span className='loader'></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }

    return (
        <>
.......
        </>
    );
}

export default Login;

Login.getLayout = function getLayout(page) {
    return <MainLayout>{page}</MainLayout>;
};
```

Same way, when router redirect login page to home page i am getting double notification. please give me proper solution.

Comment: In your next.config.js file, you can try using const nextConfig = { 
   reactStrictMode: false
 }

Answer (score 0):

If you are using React 18 with `StrictMode`, then in development **only** a double-render is purposely occurring. This section of the documentation highlights this feature:

https://reactjs.org/blog/2022/03/29/react-v18.html#new-strict-mode-behaviors

Essentially, it's helping you deal with a bad side effect:

```js
if (server.auth) {
  router.push("/");
  toast.success("You are already logged In");
}
```

Since `server` is a context and `auth` is set, when React 18 performs its intentional double-render, your component triggers this twice. Because when your login page unmounts and remounts, context.auth is preserved.

A better way to handle to handle this situation would be to use a single hook the redirect logic where you detect `location.pathname`. For example:

`useRedirects.ts`

```js
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useLocation, useRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import toast from 'toast';

const useRedirects = () => {
  const location = useLocation();
  const { pathname } = location;
  const router = useRouter();
  
  // when pathname changes, do stuff
  useEffect(() => {
    // if on dashboard and not authed, force login page
    if (pathname === '/dashboard' && !server.auth) {
      router.push("/auth/login");
      toast.success("Please login to access dashboard");
    }
    // if on login page and authed, go to dashboard
    if (pathname === '/login' && server.auth) {
      router.push("/");
      toast.success("You are already logged In");
    }
  }, [pathname]);
   
  return null;
};
```

Include this hook in your `app.js` file component:

```js
import useRedirects from './useRedirects';

const App = () => {
  useRedirect();
  // ...
  // return ...
};

export default App;
```

Now you can remove this from your dashboard page:

```js
if (!server.auth) {
  router.push("/auth/login");
  toast.success("Please login to access dashboard");
}
```

And remove this from your login page:

```js
if (server.auth) {
  router.push("/");
  toast.success("You are already logged In");
}
```

Essentially, the double render happens on purpose in React 18 to help you identify bad code (improperly created side effects). It doesn't happen in production and should help identify issues.

Comment: great, this way i can redirect from a specific page(url). 
but i want to redirect from all sub pages under the dashboard. how can i dot it on your way?

Comment: The most simplistic way to achieve this is using `startsWith()`

`if (pathname.startsWith('/dashboard') && !server.auth) {`